# Why we need only to show $\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{v_1,v_j}]=\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{w,v_j}]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is from "Mathematics for Economists" by Simon and Blume.

> **Definition:** Let $\mathbf{v_1,\dots,v_k}$ be a fixed set of $k$ vectors in $R^m$.Then, we define $\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{v_1,\dots,v_k}]\equiv\{c_1\mathbf{v_1}+\dots+c_k\mathbf{v_k}:c_1,\dots,c_k\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
>
> **Lemma:** Let $\mathbf{v_1,\dots,v_k}$ be a collection of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$. For some $j>1$, let $$\mathbf{w}=c_1\mathbf{v_1}+c_j\mathbf{v_j},\text{ with $c_1\neq0$.}$$Then, $\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{v_1,\dots,v_k}]=\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{w,\dots,v_k}].$
>
> **Proof:** We need only to show $\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{v_1,v_j}]=\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{w,v_j}]$.(**Why?**)$$\text{$\vdots \vdots \vdots$}$$etc.

I have no answer for this "**Why**".Please let me know why we have only to check Lemma for  two vectors.

Comment: I have no idea why this is an important step. 

$\mathbf{v}\in\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{w,v_2,...,v_k}]$ implies $\mathbf{v}\in\mathcal{L}[\mathbf{v_1,v_2,...,v_k}]$ and vice versa by simply expanding, redistributing and maybe dividing through by $c_1$.

Comment: I think the idea is that if $\mathcal L[\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_j]=\mathcal L[\mathbf w,\mathbf v_j]$, then $\mathcal L[\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\mathbf v_j]=\mathcal L[\mathbf w,\mathbf v_2,\mathbf v_j]$, and so $\mathcal L[\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\mathbf v_3,\mathbf v_j]=\mathcal L[\mathbf w,\mathbf v_2,\mathbf v_3,\mathbf v_j]$, and so on. But you'd have to prove that first.

Comment: I think it is just sloppiness on the author's part. Unless the author has shown how ${\cal L}$ relates for different numbers of vectors, then I cannot see a why for the **Why?** above! Besides, it doesn't simplify the proof in any substantial way as far as I can see.